# How to Upgrade Magento 2.2.6 to 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.2.7

I use Magento 2.2.6 with a theme. Arround 2200 products. I want to upgrade the store to 2.2.7.

Can someone redirect me to steps to upgrade to 2.2.7 from 2.2.6?

Thanks,
Niraj

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I am a non-technical person. I am trying to find steps to upgrade but not getting some legit info.

Comment: In one of the help, they asked to do it from admin> upgrade info. when I tried to add private key, it is showing error. So unable to do it from admin too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you are attempting to the upgrade directly on your Live website , i won't recommend it as if upgrade fails you won't be able to recover the website on your own as you are a non-technical person .

If you still up for it here is steps you need to do

1) Backup your website (both source code and DB).

Depending upon your hosting you would have to Create a SSH account and connect via [PUTTY](https://www.putty.org/)

2) You should put your store in maintenance mode while upgrading. To enable maintenance mode:
After connecting using PUTTY , navigate to magento root directory and run

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

3) Run command to add new version of magento 2 your composer, I am assuming you are CE edition and your hosting comes with composer installed .

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.7 --no-update
composer update
```

4) You would be asked to put in credentials (To get these credentials check [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html)) , Put in your private and public key from your account

5)Now time to remove cache, generation ,run upgrade and indexing. Run the following command line at root folder:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generation/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

6): Check the current Magento 2’s version
Next, you can check the Magento 2’s version by running the command.

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Comment: i just created the staging version.

Comment: Great then you are good to try the above steps @NirajNagar

Comment: i executed composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.7 --no-update ---- on putty it is asking for user name. Which username and password?

Comment: You can get that from magento.com account

Comment: got it. it worked. thanks.. no moving to next step.

Comment: symfony/contracts suggests installing psr/cache (When using the Cache contracts)
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/cache-contracts-implementation
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/translation-contracts-implementation
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

Comment: Great , Do accept and upvote the answer so that other users can take reference from it

Comment: above posted are the last few lines. when it stopped. Is it done?

Comment: its done, its just a suggestion

Comment: Thanks Vishwas. All done, now it is showing 2.2.7. The only issue I found that theme is not working. Can you please guide me for theme also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90505/discussion-between-niraj-nagar-and-vishwas-bhatnagar).

Comment: Just logged in and found that Admin section is broken, and left links are not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: php bin/magento s:s:d -f; --- 
php bin/magento c:f; --- used these two command provided by the theme company and all working now. thanks for all the guidance.

Comment: Try running bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: If i have to upgrade to 2.2.8, will these above steps will work? Any change in any of the above command?

Comment: as long as your theme and extensions are compatible with new version, then it should works.